# Cython behaving strangely with string member function of structs

Tags: python, c++, struct, cython

I've got a struct that looks like this:

foo.h:

```
struct A { 
    string a;
    string b;
};
```

It has the matching definition in a .pyx file, as well as a python wrapper:

lib_foo.pyx:

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    cdef struct A:
        string a
        string b

cdef class PyA:
    cdef A* thisptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = <A*>malloc(sizeof(A))
    cdef A* getThis(self):
        return self.thisptr
    def bar(self):
        self.thisptr.a = "Hello" # works fine!
    def bar2(self):
        return self.thisptr.a # this too!

def bar(PyA f):
    f.getThis().a = "Hello"

def bar2(PyA a):
    return f.getThis().a
```

This builds fine without any problems, I get a libfoo.so out of it, which I use in a simple test script:

```
import libfoo
f = libfoo.PyA()
#f.bar() no problems
libfoo.bar(f) # this line and the next have unpredictable behavior!
print libfoo.bar2(f)
```

Over repeated runs, sometimes this will successfully print "Hello", and other times a segfault. Even stranger, the two functions bar and bar2 seem to work just fine as member functions of class PyA. I have done a bunch of cython wrapping, using just such a getThis() function in order to supply pointers to classes and structs, never had a problem until now. Could it be the strings causing the issue?

edit: setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import distutils.util as du
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import os

os.environ["CC"] = "/app/gcc/4.8.2/bin/g++"
os.environ["CXX"] = "/app/gcc/4.8.2/bin/g++"
os.environ["CPP"] = "/app/gcc/4.8.2/bin/g++"
os.environ["CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER"] = "/app/gcc/4.8.2/bin/g++"

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        name = "libfoo",
        sources = ["lib_foo.pyx"],
        include_dirs = ["/usr/local/include", "/usr/include"],
        library_dirs = ["/usr/local/lib", "/usr/lib"],
        language = "c++",
    )]

setup(
    name = "libfoo",
    cmdclass = {"build_ext" : build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
    )
```

Comment: Can we have complete and runnable examples? Your current ones don't compile.

Comment: alright I've included my setup.py in the edit. But it should compile just fine, what kind of compilation errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to tell Cython that `struct A` has C++ class semantics (`cdef cppclass`), not C struct semantics (`cdef struct`), because it has nontrivial constructor due to embedded strings.

```
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "foo.h":
    cdef cppclass A:
        string a
        string b
```

Then allocate with operator `new`, not malloc, exactly as you would do in C++.

```
def __cinit__(self):
    self.thisptr = new A()
```

Bypassing the constructor and using uninitializes instances is why you get crashes.

Don't forget to delete this object when Python wrapper is disposed:

```
def __dealloc__(self):
    del self.thisptr
```

Also, it's a good idea to provide explicit method for deterministically releasing C-level resources (independent of Python GC):

```
def dispose(self):  # or "close" or whatever
    del self.thisptr
    self.thisptr = NULL
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm not able to change the c++ source. I have gotten this method of wrapping classes, not structs, to work. I was hoping there would be a similar feature for structs.

Comment: It has nothing to do with C++ source. You need to inform _Cython_ that `struct A` has C++ semantics using `cdef cppclass` instead of `cdef struct`. Actual keyword used to declare it in C++ is irrelevant.

Comment: whoa, that did it. struct and class are clearly different things, how is it cython can interpret them as the same? I get that classes are like structs, but in the OOP sense. 

In any case, enjoy your bounty :)